# CheckBoxFor always returns false when inside a for-loop

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have an Index-view with a list of categories. When I click to edit one of them, I can edit it "inline" in the same view. But I cannot get a `true` from the checkbox. If I manually set `Published` to `true` in the database, the checkbox is checked, but a submit sets it back to `false`.

This is the viewmodel:

```
public class ProductCategoryVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
}
```

The view's razor code (note that even though I have a list of categories, I'm only editing one of them - the one where `Model[i].Id == id`.):

```
@model List<ProjectName.Models.ViewModels.ProductCategoryVM>
string action = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] != null
    ? this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
    : "";
int id = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] != null
    ? int.Parse(this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString())
    : 0;
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    if (Model[i].Id == id && action == "Edit")
    {
        <form asp-action="Index">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" name="Id" />
            <input asp-for="@Model[i].Title" name="Title" />
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].Published)
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    }
    else if (Model[i].Id == id && action == "Delete")
    {
        // Confirm delete.
    }
    else
    {
        // List out the rest of the categories with link to Edit and Delete:
        <a asp-action="Index" 
           asp-route-action="Edit"
           asp-route-id="@Model[i].Id">Edit</a>
        <a asp-action="Index" 
           asp-route-action="Delete"
           asp-route-id="@Model[i].Id">Delete</a>
        @Model[i].Title
    }
}
```

This the HTML output for `Title` and `Published`:

```
<input name="Title" type="text" id="z1__Title" value="Test category" />
<input id="z1__Published" name="[1].Published" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

In this case, the category is saved to the database with `Title = "Test category"` and `Published = false`.

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id, string action,
    [Bind("Id,Published,Title")] ProductCategory productCategory)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case "Create":
                // Create a new category
            case "Edit":
                _context.Update(productCategory);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            case "Delete":
                // Delete a category
            default:
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
    return View(productCategory);
}
```

Comment: Should be obvious when you look at the `name` attributes. But you should never set the `name` attribute (or the `value` attribute) when using TagHelpers or `HtmlHelper` methods, and you hack means you have other issues (you cannot get client side validation for example)

Comment: @StephenMuecke But I'm not setting `id` or `name` for the checkbox? Are the other inputs (hidden and text) affecting the HtmlHelper?

Comment: Your view is based on `List<ProductCategoryVM>` but you are trying to bind to a single object in your POST method. Your code is an awful hack and poor performance but you have changed the `name` attribute for both `Id` and `Title` (again, awful practice and should never be done) to make your hack work, but you did not do the same for the `Published` property

Comment: I made it work by replacing the HtmlHelper with '<input type="checkbox" name="Published" @localVarToSetCheckedOrNot value="true" />'. Do you have any pointers for me on how to do this the proper way, keeping all CRUD-actions on one single view?

Comment: You either have one form and allow the user the edit any or all records, and post back the collection, or you just display the records with links and either redirect to an edit view  or open a modal form to edit it. Your code poor performance, a confusing UI (a user might edit 2 or 3 records and hit a submit button and not even know it failed), and means you can never get client side validation, and if server side validation fails, you cannot return the view (all the data the user entered would be lost)